# Access Aurora-PostgreSQL cluster with DB credentials from Amazon Secrets Manager in EC2 | Bash?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

(Note: Beginner here)

Currently, I am on an EC2 instance within the same VPC and Subnet as my Aurora-PostgreSQL cluster.

What I am trying to do is create a bash script or a Python script to spin up an EC2, run the script, and turn off. This script should connect to the PostgresDB and add the PostGIS extension so that the DB can interpret and be queried for spatial data

I am able to retrieve all DB credentials from Amazon Secrets Manager using the following command:

```
aws --region <region> secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <arn> --query SecretString --output text
```

Using jq package, I can extract the username and password and store the returned value as a variable, e.g.:

```
password=$(aws --region <region> secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <arn> --query SecretString --output text | jq .password)
```

Using these credentials, I tried to access the DB via:

```
psql "postgresql://${username}:${password}@<endpoint>:5432"
```

to which I get an instant response:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<username>"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<username>"
```

I tried to login manually as well to ensure the correct username and password were given, however the same error is provided.

Now, I am questioning if I am doing this properly.

1. Can I utilize my credentials to login via Bash?
2. Should I instead create a Python script to deal w the connections instead, clone it, and connect to my DB instance via Python?

Comment: My assumption for your use case was wrong. I thought you were asking about the RDSDataClient and use of Secret Manager when using that client to perform database CRUD operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer- this is quite intriguing as I've learned much from your response. What I am trying to do is create a bash script or a Python script to spin up an EC2, run the script, and turn off. This script should connect to the PostgresDB and add the PostGIS extension so that the DB can interpret and be queried for spatial data. @smac2020

Added context to the OG post.